# Get the last value of a entity field with condition

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I'm making a website for performance monitoring.

I have 2 tables:

- Users table linked in one-to-Many with performances
- Performances table linked in Many-to-one with users table

I just wanna get the last weight **which is not null** in my table performances and display it in twig

[database screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkFI2.jpg)
For exemple in this database, the result would be : 80

I tried with queries but I get an arror message so I don't know how to do
Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this could helps you.
I suppose you have a repository class for your Performance entity. I would use this kind of code for a Symfony3 application

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Repository; //replace AppBundle by the name of your bundle

use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator;

/**
 * PerformanceRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
class PerformanceRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{

    public function getLastWeigth()
    {
       $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('p')
            ->from($this->_entityName, 'p')
            ->expr()->isNotNull('p.weight')
            ->orderBy('p.date', 'desc') 
            ->setMaxResults(1);
       $query = $qb->getQuery();
       $result = $query->getSingleResult();

       return $result;
    }
}
```

Edit: here is an Exemple of use in the controller in a Symfony 3 application:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Controller\Performance;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use AppBundle\Repository\PerformanceRepository;

class PerformanceController extends Controller
{

    public function lastWeightAction()
    {
        $repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('AppBundle:Performance');
        $lastPerformance = $repo->getLastWeigth();

        //some other code
    }
}
```

Edit2:
If you need to get the last weight by a user Id:

```
class PerformanceRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{

    public function getLastWeigth($userId)
    {
       $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('p')
            ->from($this->_entityName, 'p')
            ->join('p.user', 'u')
            ->where('u.id = :userId')
            ->expr()->isNotNull('p.weight')
            ->orderBy('p.date', 'desc') 
            ->setMaxResults(1);
            ->setParameter(':userId', $userId);
       $query = $qb->getQuery();
       $result = $query->getSingleResult();

       return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, we are ok that the command to get it in the controler is : $lastWeight= $user->getPerformance()->getLastWeight(); ?

Because it says : Attempted to call an undefined method named "getLastWeight" of class "Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection".

Comment: I edited my answer to show you how I use the repository method in my controller

Comment: Ok, now I get this error : Call to a member function orderBy() on string 

But date field is a datetime type I don't understand

Comment: Watch the type of date property of your enity in Performance.orm.yml file. 
If date property of your entity  is not a datetime type then change it to datetime and do doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle and doctrine:schema:update

Comment: Thanks again for your help , just another question , I don't understand where in your code you specify the user weight we want to target.

Comment: Do you mean you need to get the last weight by an user id ? if yes do you have a "user" or "users" property in your Performance entity ?

Comment: Yes I need to do that !
I have this : 
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Users", inversedBy="performance")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="SET NULL")
     */
    private $user;

Comment: And this :

    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

Comment: I updated my answer to show you how I would get the last weigth by an userId.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help !